# Use css bootstrap with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display my variable called "data.tickets[i].description" in my table and create a new row every time i have a new description  but it's not working, nothing is display. here is my code :

```
function displaytickets(){
    var $mytable = $('table').addClass('table table-condensed table-hover')
    $mytable.append($('<tbody>'))
    $mytable.append($('<th scope=row>').addClass('mylist'));
    $('body').append($mytable);
    var newid = {};
    $("#mylist").empty();
    $("#nbtick").html("");
    $("#mycontent").html("");
    var y = document.getElementById("mySecond").value;
    localStorage.setItem("monauteur", y);
    console.log(y);
    $.ajax({
      url:"https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+y+"/tickets/requested.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cors: true ,
      contentType:'application/json',
      secure: true,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(""));
      },
      success: function (data){
          for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
              var new_table = $mytable.clone();
              new_table.find('.mylist').text(data.tickets[i].description);
              var mytitle = data.tickets[i].subject;
              var description = data.tickets[i].description;
              var status = data.tickets[i].status;
              var myid = data.tickets[i].id;
              console.log(data.tickets[i]);
              var create = data.tickets[i].created_at;
              var created = moment(created).format("MM-DD-gggg");
              var nbticket = data.tickets.length;
          }
          $("#nbtick").append('<p>'+nbticket+'</p>');
      }, 
  });

  $("#idisplay").css("display", "none");


}
```

Comment: can you create a sample Js fiddle with your code ?

Comment: are you calling this function anywhere?

Comment: Yes i called it^^ i have done some test and the function is well executed. sorry i can't do a JS fiddle, because it will show my login and password for the API

Comment: you can mock the API call , refer this jsfiddle  to know more on mocking ajax request . https://jsfiddle.net/hofo/x7s9c4wL/

Comment: You are cloneing $mytable but do not append it again.